# nba python file reading

Tags: python, file

I have a homework assignment and we need to go through a file we created and take the players that have played more than 50 games and have an average shooting percentage of over 50 percent (which we have to calculate by dividing the two numbers).

I have formatted my code like this, because I am trying to index into the new lines I have created from the text. This is not working for me and I was wondering if anyone could point me in a new direction please. Thank you.

```
f = open("stats-clean.txt", "r")
lines = f.read()
for line in lines:
    new_lines = lines.split("\n")
report = []
new_lines.remove(new_lines[0])
for item in new_lines:
    if int(item[4])/int(item[5]) > .50 and int(item[3]) >= 50:
        report.append(item)
print(report)
f.close()
```

Comment: What error are you running into? Could you paste your file here?

Comment: @letsc http://foureyes.github.io/csci-ua.0002-spring2015-008/homework/hw10/stats-clean.txt this is a link that has all of the information I saved in my file

Comment: @Tyler this is what pops up when I run it: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/norahenick/Documents/Introduction to Computer Programming/Homework10/nba.py", line 83, in <module>
    if int(item[4])/int(item[5]) > .50 and int(item[3]) >= 50:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: It looks like you're not splitting the lines properly, instead you're iterating over individual characters.

Comment: @Tyler thank you - going to try changing how I split and then look at it again

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the format of your input, but one problem is that you're trying to compare integers to floats. if you caste item[4] and item[5] as ints e.g.

```
int(item[4])/int(item[5]) > .50
```

then the resolution of the division above will always give you an int. So...

```
int(4)/int(5) = 0
```

But,

```
float(4)/float(5) = 0.8
```

So it is likely that you're not really making the comparison that you wanted, which could lead to that section of the if statement resolving to false.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know, there is an easier way to do this, I just scripted this solution for fun.

```
import csv

with open('stats-clean.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    player_data = list(reader)

for i in player_data[1:]:
    name , pos, team, gp, fgm, fga = i
    if gp > 50:
        try:
            print 'Player: {0} Average Shooting per game {1}'.format(name, ( float(gp)/float(fga) ) )
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print 'ZERO SHOTS : Player {} has {} shots'.format( name, fga )
```

Comment: if @GC123UNC asnwered your original question , please accept it

Answer (score 0):

A key problem here is that `new_lines` is a list of strings, for example

```
>>> new_lines[0]
'Julyan Stone,PG,DEN,4,0.5,0.5'
```

`item[4]` of this string is the character `'a'` so when you go to cast with `int` you get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`.

You need to split each element of new_lines using `split(',')`. So for example

```
>>> new_lines[1].split(',')
['Chris Wilcox', 'PF', 'BOS', '61', '1.8', '2.5']
```

Now you can do your casting as `item[4]` is `'1.8'` and perform your conditional test but use `floats` instead of `int` to turn the strings into numbers as pointed out by @GC123UNC

Also notice that the loop

```
for line in lines:
    new_lines = lines.split("\n")
```

is superfluous: `lines` is a string: one `split('\n')` gives you the list `new_lines` that you need. You need to loop through the elements of `new_lines` and split on `,` so that you can do your conditional test.

Instead of `remove` use slicing: `newlines[1:]`.

You might wish to consider using `lines = f.readlines()` rather than `lines = f.read()`. The latter returns a string that you need to split and then split again. The former gives you a list which you can `strip()` and split on `,`  (something like `line.strip().split(',')`)